# A program with multiple processes cannot be called. Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I write two programs testa.py and testb.py, testb.py will call test2 function contained in testa.py.  But test2 doesn`t run. Why?
testa.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def test01():
    print("hello this is a test function\n")

def test2():
    print("hello this is test2 func\n")
    q = Queue(1)
    processess=[]
    for i in range(5):
        pr = Process(target=test01,args=(q))
        pr.start()
        processess.append(pr)
    
    try:
        end = 0;
        while end!=5:
            item = q.get()
            end+=1
            yield item
    finally:
        for p in processess:
            if p.is_alive():
                p.terminate()
            p.join()
        q.close()
if __name__=='__main__':
    test01()
```

Testb.py:

```
from testa import test01, test2

def main():
    print("hello\n")
    test2()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And i will get this output

```
(base) D:\code_area\python\TEST>python testb.py 
hello

(base) D:\code_area\python\TEST>
```

it seems  test2 func does not run at all.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py`?

Comment: no , i just create those two .py files

Comment: Then you can make one, might work.

Comment: Make sure you saved your code and that you're executing the right file. The problem is not import because the error would be different then, so it must be about code being actually different than what you posted - either you don't call test2 or test2 doesn't have the print.

Comment: when i annotate test2 function about multiprocess , it will print "hello this is test2 func" rightly. @BrainFlooder

Comment: when i annotate test2 function about multiprocess , it will print "hello this is test2 func" rightly. By the way, my os is win10 @h4z3

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is.
When i annotate 'yield item', project will run rightly.